# G-Suite group, always use group address in replies

Tags: gmail, google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

I want to use a g-suite group for a support address. The group will include a number of people in the company, who are authorised to respond to support requests.

I would like to set it up so replies will be sent from the group "support@..." address, rather than from the individual group member.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't require individual group members to set their "Send mail as:"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set the Post As The Group setting to the level you require.
[image]

Then when posting, Post on behalf of the group instead.
[image]

Comment: This is functional but not practical since it will always default to posting as the user and not the group. Is there a setting or configuration that would make "post on behalf of Support" the default choice for posting?

Answer (score -1):

For the moment there is no set as default poster, would be nice though.
We have it set up to reply from email as the group. and we check the interface for marking things as complete and assigning them.